# Find the location name where the user is setting

Tags: android, localization, geolocation

I'm making a small personal application and I want to know how to detect/find where is the user setting, I mean for example If I'm setting in **McDonald "A"**, I want to have as location **"McDonald A"** not the address or something else. I tried with `Geocoder` but it gives me almost for many locations the address not the name for example. Is there some others possibility to find out the name of the locations?

I don't have code and I don't need, just I didn't find a solution, tell me just how and I will make the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find a service which would have Places stored in a database and which would also have functionality which with you could search the places.

Unfortunately there are not services which would cover all possible places, so you might need to search for ones that would give you the place categories you want to use.

One places service I could recommend is the HERE Places service, which has REST service API defined for it. check developer.here.com for more info

Comment: Google doesn't offer such service? because I'm using also google place API